# How to get user.email in server using auth0 and node.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, auth0

On my frontend, I can see the email through:

```
  console.log(auth.profile.email)
```

Then I call this service to retrieve some information from the backend, it's protected so you need to be logged in to get anything back:

```
var metadata_req = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:80/protected/all/metadata"
    }
```

On the backend, I'm using node.js and this to verify that the user is logged in before doing a request:

```
var jwtCheck = express-jwt({
    secret: new Buffer(config.secret, 'base64'),
    audience: config.client_id
});
```

But if I print out req.user, I only see iss, sub, aud, exp and iat. I would like to see the email as well.

Comment: how are you passing the email to the request ?

Comment: I tried using data: {email: auth.profile.email} in metadata_req but that didn't work.

Comment: you can't pass data in messageBody for GET request

Comment: Then how would I do it to make sure the server has the email of the person logged in?

Comment: simply use post request , pass the messagebody as you are doing, in nodejs simply get your email from req.body.email

Comment: But the url is a GET url, it's not a POST at all - so that wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you update your answer with user schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get profile information in `req.user` by including the email permission when your user initially logs in.

For example, using lock in angular would look like this:

```
auth.signin({
    authParams: {
      scope: 'openid email'
    }
  }, function(profile, token) {
    // stuff
  }, function(err) {
    // error handling
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your API definition from `"all/metadata"` to `"all/metadata/:emailId"`

Call your API

```
var metadata_req = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:80/protected/all/metadata/{your_email_id}"
    }
```

In NodeJS retrieve you email_id from `req.params.emailId`